# Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted #1728

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

can some one help me
i want to create a procedure in mysql and this happens
MySQL said: Documentation

## 1728 - Cannot load from mysql.proc. The table is probably corrupted

i tried the solution i found here at stackoverflow and here
http://webcheatsheet.com/sql/Fix_Cannot_load_from_mysql.proc._The_table_is_probably_corrupted.php

when i run the command on command prompt it says
'mysql_upgrade.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

btw im using xampp, thank you

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me :

1. Run command prompt (with Admin Privileges),
2. change directory and move to C:\xampp\mysql\bin (using "cd" command)
3. type mysql_upgrade and enter

You must be in this folder => C:\xampp\mysql\bin>

Hope this help

Answer (score 3):

Using xampp, you could solve in in few steps.

**Step 1**: On XAMPP Control Panel, click the Shell shortcut.

[image: xampp control panel]

**Step 2:** On the cmd, type `mysql_upgrade` and press `enter`

[image: XAMPP Shell]

Answer (score 2):

you should type this command in the right path

in your case  i think the default path will be **C:\xampp\mysql\bin**
then hold Shift and press a mouse right click there and choose open command window here 
and just type
 **mysql_upgrade**
and that will solve your problem 1728 as mine before